AVR ATtiny1626 bizarre infinite interrupt problem
I have an ATtiny1626 code that I'm in the early stages of just getting the modules going on my custom board for my client.
I had some issues with my interrupts being called indefinitely over and over.
It did get it resolved for the ADC interrupts by manually clearing the flag inside the ISR. But for my SPI it just doesn't seem to work.
I have searched for ny solution or remotely similar cases i found did not help :/
As you can se in my code, I've only sent one byte of data thru the SPI in the SPI_init function. I'll include all my code just in case anyone asks for it, You can ignore ADC & USART sections:
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define BAUDR (F_CPU * 64)/(16UL * 9600)

int i = 0;
int j = 0;

void __delay_ms(int n) // for variable as a delay amount...
{
    while (n--)
    {
        _delay_ms(1);
    }
}

void ADC_init()
{
    PORTA.DIR |= 0x04; // make AIN2(POT) Input for ADC
    ADC0.MUXPOS = 0x02; // ADC is connected to AIN2
    _delay_us(250);
    ADC0.CTRLA = 0x01; // ADC enabled
    ADC0.CTRLB = 0x0F; // Prescalar = /64
    // VREF = VDD (CTRLC = 0x00)
    //ADC0.INTCTRL = 0x01; // Result Ready Interrupt enabled
    ADC0.CTRLE = 10;
    //ADC0.CTRLF = 0x20;
    ADC0.COMMAND = 0x01; // Immediate Sample Start 8-bit
}

void SPI_init()
{
    PORTA.DIRSET = 0x02;
    PORTC.DIRSET = 0x0D;
    _delay_us(10);
    
    SPI0.CTRLA = SPI_ENABLE_bm | SPI_MASTER_bm | SPI_PRESC_DIV128_gc; // SPI ON MAster Prescalar/128
    //SPI0.CTRLB = 0x04;
    SPI0.INTCTRL = SPI_IE_bm; // Interrupt enabled;
    _delay_us(10);
    SPI0.DATA = 0xCC;
}

void UART_init()
{
    // Set the baud rate in the BAUD register
    USART0.BAUD = BAUDR;

    USART0.CTRLB |= USART_TXEN_bm | USART_RXEN_bm;

    USART0.CTRLC = USART_CHSIZE_8BIT_gc | USART_PMODE_DISABLED_gc | USART_SBMODE_1BIT_gc;
}

void Putc(char c)
{
    while(!(USART0.STATUS & USART_DREIF_bm));
    USART0.TXDATAL = c;
    //_delay_ms(1);
}

void Puts(char *s)
{
    for(int a = 0; s[a] != '\0'; a++)
    {
        Putc(s[a]);
        //_delay_ms(1);
    }
}

void shift_out(uint8_t bit) {
    if (bit) {
        PORTC.OUTSET = 0x04;  // Set SER high
    } else {
        PORTC.OUTCLR = 0x04; // Set SER low
    }
    PORTC.OUTSET = 0x01;  // Set SRCLK high
    _delay_us(1);                   // Short delay to ensure timing
    PORTC.OUTCLR = 0x01; // Set SRCLK low
    _delay_us(1); 
    //_delay_ms(125);
}

int main()
{
    sei();
    // Output enable DISP_EN and DISP_DP
    PORTB.DIR = 0x26;
    PORTB.OUT = 0x22;
    //_delay_ms(2000);
    ADC_init();
    _delay_ms(10);
    SPI_init();
    UART_init();
   //_delay_ms(500);
    /*
    shift_out(1);
    shift_out(0);
    shift_out(0);
    shift_out(0);
    shift_out(0);
    shift_out(0);
    shift_out(1);
    shift_out(0);
    PORTA.OUTCLR = 0x02;  
    _delay_us(1);                   
    PORTA.OUTSET = 0x02;
    _delay_us(1);  
    */
    
    while (1)
    { 
        _delay_ms(500);
        //PORTB.OUTTGL = 0x20;
        
    }
    return 0;
}

// Interrupts had an infinte loop isisue so flags had to be cleared manually...

ISR(ADC0_RESRDY_vect)
{
    //ADC0.INTFLAGS |= ADC_RESRDY_bm;
}

ISR(SPI0_INT_vect)
{
    // this bit and the variable i are only for the temporary purpose of checking wether the interrupt is called on repeat or not
    i++;
    if(i >= 10)
    {
        PORTB.OUTCLR = 0x20;
    }
    // 74HC595 Latch Pulse
    PORTA.OUTSET = 0x02;
    _delay_us(3);
    PORTA.OUTCLR = 0x02;

    
    //uint8_t d = SPI0.DATA;
    SPI0.INTFLAGS = SPI_IF_bm;
}

I can tell the interrupts is being called over and over as in the SPI ISR, the counter variable i exceeds 10000!!!! I am very confused and im not sure what to do. On top of this, The SPI is connected to shift register and 7seg, And no data seem to be sent either as latching the shift register in the ISR does nothing, and FYI, the hardware seems fine i used bit banging and it worked perfectly.
Furthermore the commented blink code in while loop in main also runs extremely slow when the interrupt of SPI is enabled, suggesting its being called over and over slowing down the delay_ms
Clearing the flags manually didn't really solve anything
searching for solution just made me more certain that there is a "reason" that makes the interrupt persistently being called over and over
but the "reason" is where i don't know what is happening :/
*** EDIT: Ive updated the code a bit, but still no success, And on top of this, SPI sent data(if even anything is sent) doesn't seem to change anything on the Shift Reigster i have connected to my 7segment
Any thoughts  on tht?(and again, the hardware is fine as bit banging works just fine)

One of the do's and don'ts for Interrupt is "Don't use delay()` in the ISR.

The i is a global variable in your code, it has been used both in the ISR functions, as well as in the puts() for...loop. BTW, the i in the ISR will keep increment until it overflow and reset to 0, I don't think that's what you want.

Read TB3215-Getting Started with SPI to see how to configure and use the SPI interrupt.

BTW, please read TB3262 AVR1000b: Getting Started with Writing C-Code for AVR® MCUs for coding style instead of using magic numbers all over the code.

@hcheung I understand that the global i variable is used all over the place. But if you actually look at the state the code is at right now, the ADC ISR and the Puts functions aren't eve used...

IIRC, the SPI IRQ flag is not being cleared when the ISR is entered; you'll have to clear that one by hand.

@emacsdrivesmenuts Isn't that what SPI0.INTFLAGS |= SPI_IF_bm; does? Or is there some oddball restriction like having to read the flag register followed by reading a data register to clear flags? That's at least how it works on the Motorola-flavoured parts that heavily inspired AVR.

Is there a PORTx.INTFLAGS flag that would need clearing as well?

@emacsdrivesmenuts In ATTiny1626 The IF is
cleared by hardware when executing the corresponding interrupt vector.. Probably you confused it with I²C interrupt flag. But writing 1 to SPI interrupt flag is not correct as well.

@MSSJCODER the Puts functions aren't in used is not an excuse for a potential bug. One best practice of c/c++ programming should have always in mind is try to avoid global variables whenever is possible, and always declare the variable at where it is needed, if you do for(int i=0; i<whatever; i++) then that i declared in the for..loop will only has the scope within that for loop and will not create conflict and potential bug as per your code.

>the hardware is fine as bit banging works just fine Your bit banging uses PC2/PC0 for MOSI/SCK. Hardware SPI by default uses PA1/PA3 (and note AIN2 conflicts with MISO). Your bitbang mixes CPHA0 and CPHA1, so slave device is able to receive data regardless of its clock phase expectation. Hardware SPI by default uses CPHA0 and CPOL0. Also in your program SS pin (PA4) is configured as input and SSD bit in SPI0.CRTLB is not set (the code is commented), so pulling SS low causes interrupt to occure. Is PA4 pulled high externally? Also don't touch IF bit in SPI0.INTFLAGS if you use SPI interrupt!

@dimich thanks for the feedback, I kind of understand the Bit banging explanation(how can i fix it with the SPI Settings? i read that 74HC595 simply operates on default settings but this whole thing is just such a mess). However, with the SPI default pin thing you mentioned, im confused(Why would MOSI and SCK not be the default SPI pins and how can i change that?) Regarding the SS pin, Even enabling SSD bit and making the entire PORTA output, The interrupt is getting called on repeat :/ .

@MSSJCODER 74HC595 has two clock inputs: shift register clock input and storage register clock input. How do you connect them both to MCU's SCK output? Regarding pins, you said that "the hardware is fine as bit banging works just fine" but how can you know that when bitbang uses different pins than hardware SPI? Do you have two registers connected to different pin sets simoultaneously or you re-wire regsiter inputs every time when switch from bitbang to hardware SPI?

@dimich regarding the pinout on the board, MISO is conencted to nothing, MOSI is connected to DS, and SCK is conencted to the shift register clock, the PA1 that is pulsed in SPI ISR is the Storage register latch(ill edit the post and comment it a bit better). And again regarding the SPI hardware, the PA1 and PA3 default pins that you said very confused me, wouldnt the default SPI pins be MOSI and SCK pins(PC0 PC2) ?? If not, how can I change this and why is it not matching the data sheet.

@dimich one more thing that really confused me about the SPI default pins is that PA2 on the board is connected to a variable resistor, and i need that pin for the ADC to be input ,and if it does conflict with the SPI, that would be very strange both on the MCU and whoever has made the custom board for my client. can you explain a bit further about the SPI default pinout and how can i change it to MOSI and SCK

@MSSJCODER According to the datasheet 16.3.4 "SPI Pins Positions" Reset value of SPI[1:0] in SPIROUTEA is 00, so MOSI is PA1 and SCK is PA3. For PA2, since you use SPI in simplex mode and don't read data from device via MISO, it should not interfere.

OMG idk how to thank you! without you i probably would have never looked at the Port multiplexer section!! this is my first time working with Attiyn1626 and i was completely unaware of that! Huge thanks @dimich ! The data is sent properly and results can be seen now that i changed it to PC0 and PC2. Although for the recurring interrupt issue i ihad to still write 1 manually in the ISR. you said to not touch it, any thoughts on that? But either way, i have nothing to complain right now as the issue ive been dealing for about a week now is solved. Again thank you very much!

@dimich Although for the recurring interrupt issue i ihad to still write 1 manually in the ISR. you said to not touch it, any thoughts on that? But either way, i have nothing to complain right now as the issue ive been dealing for about a week now is solved. Again thank you very much! iif you want, post your solution as a standlone post on this question so ican give the green tick or whtvr it is to you! basically my first time asking a serious question myself on here.

@MSSJCODER You're welcome. The hint about PINMUX is not the answer to your original question, i think. Datasheet is your friend, always double check with it when something doesn't work. Regarding ISR, unfortunately i have no Attiny1626 near at hand to check it's exact behavior in vivo. Make sure SS pin (PC3 now) is configured as output or SSD bit is set. By the way, 74HC595 latches storage register on rising edge of STCP, so you may want to set SS low before transfer and set it high after transfer, as SPI controller usually do. No need to pulse with delay in ISR as well.

There are a whole lot of problems with this code... here are some that may be relevant for the specific problem.

The normal way to write any ISR on most MCUs including AVR, is to always clear the interrupt source flags that caused the interrupt from within the ISR. You seem surprised by this, but it's how every ISR is properly written.

On any MCU where writing a 1 clears the interrupt flag, then |= is the wrong operator to use because it results in a read-modify-write. That is, all status flags will get read and any status flag which happened to have a 1 set will get cleared, in addition to the SPI_IF_bm OR:ed in. Correct code for preserving other flags would (counter-intuitively) be SPI0.INTFLAGS = SPI_IF_bm;. This works without destroying any other flag because writing a zero has no effect.

On many MCUs, SPI flags specifically are often cleared in a peculiar way, namely by first reading the status/flag register when the flag is set, followed by an immediate read of the data register. Comments suggest that this may be the case here. If so you should do something like:
uint8_t dummy = SPI0.INTFLAGS;
uint8_t ch    = SPI0.DATA;

Note that on MCUs having this peculiar way of clearing SPI flags, there's a notoriously obscure problem when you have a debugger open and view either the specific register or a raw memory map dump. The debugger would then send read commands to the MCU and by doing so destroying the flags. You can tell if you are having this problem in case single-stepping in the debugger doesn't work, but leaving the code free-running without debugger works.

Using busy-wait delays in your program is a strong indication of poor program design - in professional code bases such things are never used. Instead hardware peripheral timers are used, even if they only set one flag which is then polled.
As for AVR skunkware libs specifically, they seem deeply problematic for a lot of other reasons. This particular function takes a floating point(!!!) parameter, it will not work unless optimizations are enabled and it does not take the effects of interrupts in account. There is just no way you should be using this function anywhere in a 8 bit MCU, let alone in an ISR! If you look at the implementation here this was clearly written for some PC with a FPU, by PC people. On a tiny AVR with 2k RAM and no FPU, this will kill your available memory, execution time, everything. For something as mundane as a delay, which can be trivially implemented with an on-hardware timer peripheral using some 10 bytes of RAM and flash.

Variables shared between an ISR and the background program must be declared volatile to prevent incorrect optimizations. Additionally, you must also protect such a variable from race condition bugs. Otherwise you can easily end up in a situation like 1) background program reads half of i 2) Boom! Interrupt. i gets overwritten 3) background program reads the other half of i. 4) i is now corrupt in a very subtle way.
Protection against race condition bugs usually involves temporarily disabling the relevant interrupt(s) like SPI in this case, read the variable, then re-enable the interrupt. But in this case you could get rid of a lot of problems by instead using a local variable i where required.

i etc were declared int but you have no protection against integer overflow. This should at the very least be declared unsigned, because unsigned variables safely wrap-around to zero. In embedded systems, the general rule is to never use the default types of C but instead only use the types from stdint.h. And to never use signed types unless you actually need negative values, which is somewhat rare.



On most of AVR devices SPI interrupt flag is not cleared by writing 1, in opposite to many other interrupt flags. For ATtiny1626: Alternatively, the IF can be cleared by first
reading the SPIn.INTFLAGS register when IF is set and then accessing the SPIn.DATA register.

@dimich Either way the OP is doing it wrong. I can add a note about reading the register.

Yes, no need to clear that flag in ISR. Sure, there are many other problems in OP's code.

@Lundin thanks for the feedback, Although strangely still, the interrupt is still getting
called infinte. Wether i write 1 to the flag, or do the "peculiar" way u mentioned, it is still getting called multiple times. i apppreciate the feed back on the global varialb,e but right now it is my only method to track how many times hte interrupt is called. What should i do?

@Lundin I got rid of the delays, and changed the condition so i is just bigger than 10(should never get bigger than 1) and this still hasn't worked and the interrupt is called non-stop. What should i do? What else might cause the issue?

@Lundin And although this cant be an excuse, The current code structure is temporary. I have spent quite some time with AVR on simulations, and this is my first few serious projects ive taken with IRL custom boards, And im just trying to get the peripherals under my belt so i can actually implement the features and the project. On top of the SPI issue, With SPI, the shift register doesnt seem get updated, as latching shows nothing.

@MSSJCODER If you step through the ISR with your debugger and step out of it, you'll notice if it is getting repeatedly called if you end up right back in, no need for some counter. Or alternatively just toggle some GPIO whenever you enter the ISR. To rule out hardware issues you should measure the SPI pins with your oscilloscope as well.
